# Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.IEntityMaterializer' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, ms-access, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to connect my mvc core application to an existing ms access database roughly following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db), but I am getting this error at startup:

> TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.IEntityMaterializer' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

I would really appreciate any guidance at all as I'm a bit lost and there doesn't seem to be much information about this around

The app is very simple right now, and it looks like this:

**Database**

```
public class Database : DbContext
{
    public Database()
    {

    }

    public Database(DbContextOptions<Database> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    public virtual DbSet<subQCItems> subQCItems { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            // warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263 for guidance on storing connection strings.
            // Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=W:\IT\Test\company.mdb
            optionsBuilder.UseJet(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=W:\IT\Test\company Backoffice.mdb");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<subQCItems>(entity =>{
            entity.Property(e => e.Index).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.GRV).IsRequired();
        });
    }
}
```

**subQCItems**

```
public class subQCItems
{
    [Key]
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public int GRV { get; set; }
}
```

**Startup**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    var connection = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=W:\IT\Test\company Backoffice.mdb";
    services.AddDbContext<Database>(options => options.UseJet(connection));
}
```

**csproj**

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="EntityFrameworkCore.Jet" Version="2.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Don't mix EF Core versions. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` already references the latest version. `EntityFrameworkCore.Jet` is 2.0.0 and depends on EF Core 2.0. It also seem to only support .NET Framework, not .NET Core (https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkCore.Jet/2.1.0-preview5)